# What does aux mean in `ps aux`?

Tags: linux, ps

`ps aux` seems to conveniently list all processes and their status and resource usage (Linux/BSD/MacOS), however I cannot comprehend the meaning of parameter `aux` using `man ps`.

What does `aux` mean?

Comment: BTW ps = process status

Answer (score 319, accepted):

a = show processes for all users
u = display the process's user/owner
x = also show processes not attached to a terminal

By the way, `man ps` is a good resource.

Historically, BSD and AT&T developed incompatible versions of `ps`.  The options without a leading dash (as per the question) are the BSD style while those with a leading dash are AT&T Unix style.  On top of this, Linux developed a version which supports both styles and then adds to it a third style with options that begin with double dashes.

All (or nearly all) non-embedded Linux distributions use a variant of the [procps](http://procps.sourceforge.net/) suite.  The above options are as defined in the [procps `ps` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps).

In the comments, you say you are using Apple MacOS (OSX, I presume).  The OSX man page for `ps` is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/ps.1.html) and it shows support only for AT&T style.

Comment: According to my manual page (MacOS), u means "Display the processes belonging to the specified usernames"

Comment: @HowardGuo Are you sure that isn't `-u` as opposed to just `u`?

Comment: @jordanm In this manual page, there is not any explained option without leading dash, I am afraid.

Comment: @HowardGuo I have updated the answer to reflect the differences between the GNU (Linux) version of `ps` and the Apple OSX version.  This question is currently tagged "Linux".  If you are asking also about MacOS, you might want to update the tags.

Comment: Thanks very much. I just checked manual page of ps in Linux and it has information regarding `aux`, MacOS' manual page does not have such information, it might be a document bug.

Comment: OSX man page for `ps` does say "... `ps aux` still works as it did in Tiger" under "Legacy Description" section.

Comment: @dev the whole paragraph reads: _The biggest change is in the interpretation of the -u option, which now displays processes belonging to the specified username(s).  Thus, "ps -aux" will fail (unless you want to know about user "x").  As a convenience, however, "ps aux" still works as it did in Tiger._

Comment: I have to object to the comment that "`man ps` is a good resource on mac OSX. The man page, only at the very end, notes that `ps aux` is maintained as a convenience, but there is absolutely no hint that options may be specified without leading hyphens before the end, the man page is long and  richly complex, and a reader can spend a lot of time questioning his/her sanity before giving up and googling for this stackexchange question.

Answer (score 27):

`man ps` describes these options as follows:

```
   a      Lift the BSD-style "only yourself" restriction, which is imposed 
          upon the set of all processes when some BSD-style (without "-") 
          options are used or when the ps personality setting is BSD-like.  
          The set of processes selected in this manner is in addition to the 
          set of processes selected by other means.  An alternate 
          description is that this option causes ps to list all processes 
          with a terminal (tty), or to list all processes when used together 
          with the x option.

   u      Display user-oriented format.

   x      Lift the BSD-style "must have a tty" restriction, which is imposed 
          upon the set of all processes when some BSD-style (without "-") 
          options are used or when the ps personality setting is BSD-like.
          The set of processes selected in this manner is in addition to the 
          set of processes selected by other means.  An alternate 
          description is that this option causes ps to list all processes 
          owned by you (same EUID as ps), or to list all processes when used 
          together with the a option.
```

#### Example

```
$ ps aux | head -10
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.0  51120  2796 ?        Ss   Dec22   0:09 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd --system --deserialize 22
root         2  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec22   0:00 [kthreadd]
root         3  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec22   0:04 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         5  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S<   Dec22   0:00 [kworker/0:0H]
root         7  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec22   0:15 [migration/0]
root         8  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec22   0:00 [rcu_bh]
root         9  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec22   2:47 [rcu_sched]
...
saml      3015  0.0  0.0 117756   596 pts/2    Ss   Dec22   0:00 bash
saml      3093  0.9  4.1 1539436 330796 ?      Sl   Dec22  70:16 /usr/lib64/thunderbird/thunderbird
saml      3873  0.0  0.1 1482432 8628 ?        Sl   Dec22   0:02 gvim -f
root      5675  0.0  0.0 124096   412 ?        Ss   Dec22   0:02 /usr/sbin/crond -n
root      5777  0.0  0.0  51132  1068 ?        Ss   Dec22   0:08 /usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant -u -f /var/log/wpa_supplica
saml      5987  0.7  1.5 1237740 119876 ?      Sl   Dec26  14:05 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=renderer --lang=en-
root      6115  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    Dec27   0:06 [kworker/0:2]
...
```

With the above switches you'll get output regarding your processes like above.

The switches `aux` will show you:

- all the users' processes
- show you the process listed in a user oriented fashion (by user names)
- show you all processes, not just ones attached to a terminal. This will include processes such as services like crond, upowerd, etc.

Answer (score 11):

The key to understanding the [manpage](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ps&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=CentOS+7.1&arch=default&format=html) is not to search for "aux" (which I tried first), but to focus on the section that describes the kinds of parameter `ps` takes:

> This version of ps accepts several kinds of options:
>
> 1. UNIX options, which may be grouped and must be preceded by a dash.
> 2. BSD options, which may be grouped and must not be used with a dash.
> 3. GNU long options, which are preceded by two dashes.

From this, we know that `aux` is a set of (grouped) BSD options, `a`, `u` and `x`, which makes them slightly easier to look up.

- `a` and `x` control which processes are selected, and used together are explicitly described to select all processes.
- `u` outputs using the "user-oriented" format, which gives more columns, including the user id and CPU/memory usage.

Because `u` alone controls the output format, you can get "ps aux" style output just for specific processes with `ps u $pid1 $pid2 ...`.

Answer (score 0):

### ps:  process status

for me, both `/bin/ps --version` and `/usr/bin/ps --version` gets: `ps from procps-ng 3.3.16`

ps is a command provided by [procps](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps):
Command line and full screen *utilities* for browsing `procfs`, a "pseudo" file system dynamically generated by the kernel to provide information about the status of entries in its process table.

### 2 kinds of syntax

To see every process on the system using:

1. **standard syntax**

- ps -e
- ps -ef

BTW, example of `ps -u`:

- ps -u root --format=user,pid,command     # which is same as this line:
- ps -uroot --format=user,pid,command      #(What an ugly syntax!)

output is:

```
    USER         PID COMMAND
    root           1 /sbin/init splash
    root           2 [kthreadd]
    root           3 [rcu_gp]
    root           4 [rcu_par_gp]
    root           6 [kworker/0:0H-kblockd]
    root           9 [kworker/u80:0-ixgbe]
```

By this POSIX and UNIX standards, `ps -aux` means `ps -a -ux` , printing:
1. processes with tty (except session leaders) [by `-a`]
2. all processes owned by a user named "x"  [by `-ux`]  (`-u`: select processes by effective **u**ser)

Process selection options are additive (A process will be shown if it meets **any** of the given selection criteria)

> If the user named "x" (the current user?)   does not exist, `ps -aux` **may** fall to  `ps aux` ,  and print a warning

there is no `-x` option in manpage, but `ps -x` can find the same processes as `ps -ux`, (in a different output format)

- `ps -ux --format=user` gets:
  username does not exist
- `ps -x --format=user`
  gets proper results (corespond to the current user)

no wonder `manpage` reminds:

> This behavior is intended to aid in transitioning **old**
> scripts and habits.  It is fragile,  and thus should not be relied upon

---

2. **BSD syntax**:
   ps ax

- a: all users
- x: list **all** processes owned by **you** (same EUID as ps).   Or more concretely, include processes with no *controlling terminal* (include   processes not attached to a terminal).

  so,  `ax` will list all processes
- u: output in resource **u**sage format
  exampale:  `ps axu`

---

### This scene shows the convinience of zsh' s autocomplete (press tab and get hint) [image]

[image]

### This manpage is reader friendly:  https://www.mankier.com/1/ps