# Linux applications, user and system

Tags: process, ps

I was wondering if there was any CLI command that would allow me to see what applications are being run by the current user, but ones that are not system commands. for example if I run `lsof` it will show everything that is open, files, apps, system processes.

I want to be able to show what applications a user has open i.e. firefox, skype, google chrome and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ps` for this, `ps` will report a snapshot of the current processes. What you're looking for specifically might be `ps aux`.

> a = show processes for all users
>
> u = display the process's user/owner
>
> x = also show processes not attached to a terminal

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/106848/149009

You could also use `ps x -u user` to see what processes a specific user is running.